# Secondary IP adress not accessable

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

I got a second ip from my provider. 
I added it with 
`ip addr add 1.2.3.220/27 dev eth0`.

Now I can ping my new ip from my host and the vms running on the host but the ip is not external accessible. But my first ip 1.2.3.198 works quite well.

`iptables-save` does not show any rule containing `1.2.3.220` so there should be no block

```
$ ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:bf:48:7f:e9:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.198/27 brd 5.9.115.223 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 1.2.3.220/27 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:4f8:162:60c4::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::12bf:48ff:fe7f:e9f7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: External access usually needs open ports for your specific services you want to use. What do you mean by "not external accessible" ?

Comment: e.g. I started an http server which should listen to both IPs. But it is only accessible by 1.2.3.198 and not 1.2.3.220. Ping also just works on 1.2.3.198 and not on 1.2.3.220

Comment: It was a problem on my providers firewall.

Comment: Providers should no block anything by default.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the arp announce to the network switch.

Try `arping -c 1 -A -I eth0 1.2.3.220`

Comment: ζ arping -c 1 -A -I eth0 1.2.3.220                                                                                                                                                             
ARPING 1.2.3.220
Timeout

--- 1.2.3.220 statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% unanswered (0 extra)